# How can you find an element using binary search on a recursive function C?

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search

I wrote this shortcode to find element x location in a sorted array (from high to low) with complexity **O(log n)**. `n` and `arr` represent the edges of the array.
However, it doesn't seem to work properly. Any suggestions?

```
int ex2_1(int *arr, int n, int key)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return -1;
    if (arr[n / 2] == key)
        return n / 2;
    if (arr[n / 2] > key)
        return ex2_1(arr + n / 2 + 1, n - n / 2 - 1, key);
    return ex2_1(arr, n / 2, key);
}
```

for `int arr[] = { 9, 7, 7, 5, 3, 3, 3, 1 };`, `int n = 8` and `int key = 3`, I get `4` when I should get `5`.

Comment: Please use more-descriptive names for your parameters than the cryptically-named `n`. It's not immediately clear what `n` represents. As you're doing binary-search you should be passing a range or bounds, not a scalar.

Comment: "doesn't work" is never a good problem description. Please show complete code as a [mre]. That is, provide the `main` that sets up test data, calls the function and verifies the result. Also give the exact expected result vs actual result.

Comment: *"it doesn't seem to work properly."* we know, otherwise you wouldn't be here. What behavior *does* it exhibit, and how is that different than your expectations. Sample input data, coded into a proper [mcve], along a the expected results, actual results, and steps taken thus far to deduce the problem, are important to a well-formed question.

Comment: Suppose the key corresponds to the very last element of the array. What does the function return? At which recursion depth? What are the arguments at that depth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After optimization of chqrlie's code I got to this, and it works well:

```
int ex2_1(int* arr, int n, int key)
{
    if (n == 0) return -1;
    if (arr[n/2] == key) return n / 2;
    if (arr[n/2] > key)
    {
        int a = ex2_1(arr + n/2 + 1, n - n/2 - 1, key);
        if (a == -1) return -1;
        return n / 2 + 1 + a;
    }
    return ex2_1(arr, n/2, key);
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie I posted this before you added the check for res < 0

Answer (score 1):

The reason your recursive function returns erroneous results is you should offset the result of the recursive call by the offset from the start of the array given as starting point in the recursive call. This should only be done if the recursive call finds a match.

Here is a modified version:

```
int ex2_1(const int *arr, int n, int key) {
    int m = n / 2;

    if (n == 0)
        return -1;
    if (arr[m] == key)
        return m;
    if (arr[m] > key) {
        int res = ex2_1(arr + m + 1, n - m - 1, key);
        return res < 0 ? res : res + m + 1;
    } else {
        return ex2_1(arr, m, key);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is close but doesn't quite work, because you may add `n / 2 + 1` to `-1`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: good point! answer amended.